# How to Apply Glow Effect to QLabel Text in Qt?

Tags: qt, qlabel

I need to apply Glow effect to `QLabel`. Text in Black color and glow effect in white(Stroke Effect). I tried in Google but no luck.

If any one knows how apply Glow effect to `QLabel` then please tell me How to do that.

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can set it on a `QLabel`:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect

You can set a QGraphicsEffect on a widget, <strike>as long as you don't mind it not working on a Mac</strike>.

```
label = new QLabel("hello text"));
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * dse = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
dse->setBlurRadius(10);
label->setGraphicsEffect(dse);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're going to be slightly disappointed.  To apply an effect, you'll need to use a QGraphicsItem.  QLabel isn't.  You'll need to use a QGraphicsTextItem inside a QGraphicsScene instead.  That probably means you'll need to rebuild your UI if it's already implemented using QWidgets.

Comment: QLabel CAN have QGraphicsEffect set DIRECTLY as it is a QWidget!

Comment: You can set QGraphicsEffect on the QWidget, but it won't affect the widget's text, and the question is how to apply Glow Effect to QLabel Text and not on QLabel widget.

Comment: with proper styling everything is possible. QLabel's brush must have transparent background in order to make Drop Shadows work.